# Optimization of numpy mesh creation for efficient interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am reading magnetic field data from a text file. My goal is to correctly and efficiently load the mesh points (in 3 dimensions) and the associated fields (for simplicity I will assume below that I have a scalar field).

I managed to make it work, however I feel that some steps might not be necessary. In particular, reading the `numpy` doc it might be that "broadcasting" would be able to work its magic to my advantage.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
# Loaded from a text file, here the sampling over each dimension is identical but it is not required
x = np.array([-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
y = np.array([-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
z = np.array([-1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
# Create a mesh explicitely
mx, my, mz = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')  # I have to switch from 'xy' to 'ij'
# These 3 lines seem odd
mx = mx.reshape(np.prod(mx.shape))
my = my.reshape(np.prod(my.shape))
mz = mz.reshape(np.prod(mz.shape))
# Loaded from a text file
field = np.random.rand(len(mx))
# Put it all together
data = np.array([mx, my, mz, field]).T
# Interpolate
interpolation_points = np.array([[0, 0, 0]])
interpolate.griddata(data[:, 0:3], data[:, 3], interpolation_points, method='linear')
```

Is it really necessary to construct the mesh like this? Is it possible to make it more efficient?

Comment: Feel free to let me know if this should be moved to codereview.SE

Comment: Your reshape lines could use `mx = mx.ravel()` or `reshape(-1)`.  And `data = np.stack([mx,my,mz,field], axis=1)` is an alternative to `np.array`.

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: @Divakar See my comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one with `broadcasted-assignment` to generate `data` directly from `x,y,z` and hence avoid the memory overhead of creating all the mesh-grids and hopefully lead to better performance -

```
m,n,r = len(x),len(y),len(z)
out = np.empty((m,n,r,4))
out[...,0]  = x[:,None,None]
out[...,1]  = y[:,None]
out[...,2]  = z
out[...,3]  = np.random.rand(m,n,r)
data_out = out.reshape(-1,out.shape[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tested it: it works, but on my machine and for the size of data that I have I could not see a significant gain. This is still more elegant I believe than what I had. I think it's a pity that `meshgrid` does not provide that kind of output directly.

Comment: @CedricH. Smells like others are the bottleneck, I see `interpolate.griddata` being one of them.